# VLC-Qt _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) error

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, vlc-qt

I want to add [VLC-Qt](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt) to my application and currently I am struggling with following error:
[image]

I am using `VLC-Qt_1.0.1_win32_msvc2013.7z` from [here](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/releases) and building my application with MSVC 2013 32bit, so I have no idea and couldn't find anything else which resolves my issue.

Has this happened to anyone?

EDIT code:
Only code I am trying to execute is

```
_instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args());
```

EDIT2:
This is the only thing I get from app output before it crash:

```
VLC-Qt "1.0.1" initialised
Using libvlc version: "2.2.2 Weatherwax"
```

**SOLUTION:**
Issue here is that precompiled library downloaded from [here](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt) was build in Release mode where I've building my application as Debug.

Comment: Press retry and look at the call stack to find the place in your code where the error is happening.  Perhaps you're trying to free/delete a pointer that wasn't allocated with new/malloc.

Comment: I have and sometimes the app crash and sometimes it opens me some Qt related code (like header file of QList but I am not using QList...)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add official solution here.

So the problem was that I was using Release dlls while building Debug mode. You can switch build mode (bottom left corned) to Release or more general solution: edit your *.pro file:

```
Debug:LIBS       += -L.../vlc-qt/lib -lVLCQtCored -lVLCQtWidgetsd
Release:LIBS       += -L.../vlc-qt/lib -lVLCQtCore -lVLCQtWidgets
INCLUDEPATH += ../vlc-qt/include
```